# android market is not showing my published application in android 2.2,android 4.0.4 decvices?

Tags: android, android-layout

i am devloped one application it published at 2 days back in android market but it still not showing android 2.2 devices marker and android 4.0.4 device market i dont no why this is happening to me my previous apps are coming in all mobiles only this app  is not showingin android 2.2,4.0.4 device market

My manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.project"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>


    <supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true" 
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="true" 
            android:anyDensity="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
     <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"/>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/dog"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity
            android:name=".firstactivty"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CHOOSER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


         <activity
            android:name=".second activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"></activity>

    </application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your targetSdkVersion, 16 is for 4.1 and because your minSdkVersion is 7, you should be able to make it less but that might not show the Holo theme. More information is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

Comment: The link I sent has the API Level table, for 2.2 you need to set it to 8, for 2.3 to 9 and so on.